# Where do unhelpful improved suggested edits go to die?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

When I hit "Improve" on a suggested edit and un-check the "this edit was helpful" box, no item appears in the "reviews" filter of my account's "activity" tab. As specified in [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work):

> When the reviewer marks the edit as **not helpful**:
>
> - The change history records the improved edit only and the suggested edit is not shown.
> - The original editor does not get any reputation for their suggestion.

the suggestion also doesn't appear in the post's revisions.

So what happens to it? Does it get rejected by Community? Is it visible in the suggested edits history (https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/) still? Does the suggester have an entry in the "suggestions" section of *his* "activity" tab? Or does this flawed suggestion vanish into the bit bucket, never to darken the face of the site again?

Comment: This is mostly curiosity -- I can't think of a reason I'd actually _need_ to have access to such a record.

Comment: _(raising hand to wipe away my tears)_ it's the first time that title of the question made me cry

Comment: @gnat: Well, here's another tearjerker, then, if you want: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105813/where-precisely-does-feedback-on-community-generated-flags-go-to-die

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, it gets rejected by the Community user; since you are not the rejecter, it does not show in your "review" activity.

It will **always** be shown in the suggester's activity under "suggestions". It is not shown in the history for the post itself, though, because it was not approved.

I have [proposed a change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122581/improving-how-suggested-edits-are-displayed-in-your-activity-history) to both of these to make it more clear when things get rejected.

Comment: That's a good feature request. I've cast my vote in favor.

Comment: @IuliusCæsar: Yes, the person who suggested it. Since it's rejected by Community, it doesn't show as an accept/reject vote in yours.