# A rejected-but-improved suggested edit disappears into a black hole

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do unhelpful improved suggested edits go to die?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126427/where-do-unhelpful-improved-suggested-edits-go-to-die)
>   [Improving how suggested edits are displayed in your activity history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122581/improving-how-suggested-edits-are-displayed-in-your-activity-history)

As the title says; if you reject-and-improve a suggested edit, it disappears *entirely* from Stack Overflow.

[image]

I've just rejected-and-improved suggestions on [How to store record using ViewState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257607/how-to-store-record-using-viewstate) and [JavaScript function returns before JSON result arrives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257625/javascript-function-returns-before-json-result-arrives), however, for **both** of this improvements;

1. They are not listed under my [*Review Activity*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/444991/matt?tab=activity&sort=reviews)
2. No suggested edit is shown under the post history for [either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257607/how-to-store-record-using-viewstate) [post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10257625/revisions).
3. The suggested edits aren't listed on the ["All" tab of the suggested edit stats](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/suggested-edits).
4. ... or the ["Rejected" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/suggested-edits?tab=rejected&filter=day)
5. ... or the ["Improved" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/suggested-edits?tab=improved&filter=day)
6. Neither counted towards my Review count.

Comment: Well, almost entirely. Since Community is the user who rejects the edit in that case, you can still find a link [in its activity tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=reviews).

Comment: @TimStone: Oooo, I didn't know that! I still think it should be listed under the places listed in the question though!