# Can I contest a rejected edit?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

[A useful edit was rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/608379). I had previously edited the code in an answer of mine, but failed to replace a reference to a temp variable I had removed. An astute reader noticed the problem and proposed an edit -- only to have it rejected.

Basically, I would like to give the guy credit for his work, and save him from any adverse consequences of the rejected edit. What can I do?  Not much, I suppose, other than review his recent activity and +1 where it makes sense, to compensate.  But I'm thinking there should be a way to contest rejected edits somehow. Or can I flag the edit reason for moderator attention somehow?

Also [related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110804/my-edit-was-rejected-for-incorrect-and-seemingly-random-reasons-how-do-i-just), [tangentially related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129956/a-rejected-but-improved-suggested-edit-disappears-into-a-black-hole).

Comment: It's +2 rep. That's hardly a loss, really. One upvote on a good answer of the other user pays for that 5 times over!

Comment: Just edit it in yourself. Suggested code edits are often not accepted. Correct it and no harm done.

Comment: Heeded both suggestions.  Thanks for the quick replies.  Anybody care to explain why they downvoted my question?

Comment: Pff, who knows. Perhaps because you could have easily figured out the answer to the question in your title? I don't know.

Comment: See the [meta-faq#vote-differences]; votes on MSO are different from the regular Stack Exchange websites. I guess people felt that contesting the rejected edit was not needed and they expressed that with a downvote.

Comment: If you post a suggested edit, please try to fix multiple issues.

Comment: You should **never** make edits to code blocks.   Rather leave a comment to the OP and let him make the changes.   This is the case with questions and answers a-like.  Editing code blocks can change the operation/meaning of the post quite drastically.

Comment: @Lix: Thanks, that could at least explain the reasoning for rejecting.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe : what if there's only ONE issue that needs to be addressed?

Comment: @Lix : "Editing code blocks can change the operation/meaning of the post quite drastically" - but the change can sometimes be an improvement, such as it was in this case: the original code was WRONG and the edit CORRECTED it. Why would you say "**never**"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't contest an edit, although you can start a discussion on meta.

But you can re-suggest it if you really think it is useful.

But keep in mind that an edit must be substantial without changing the meaning of the post.

Answer (score 6):

Since I'm responsible for one of the reject votes, I probably should chip in.

In general, I reject suggested code edits especially when the original post was by a high-rep user. Too often do we see invalid/irrelevant edits to code, and it should not be incumbent upon reviewers to grok the entire post just to validate a code edit.

My rationale on why code edits should be discouraged:

- minor errors and typos in code are better addressed with comments. The OP is the best person to judge if the edit is correct; he/she will get notified of the comment and has the option to make the edit, ignore, or respond to it.
- major errors in the code should be downvoted instead
- for code improvements, if the editor believes there's a better way to do it he/she should post a separate answer instead

Naturally, every now and then valid edits such as this will get caught in the net. For that I am sorry, but I'm willing to take some casualties for the sake of keeping those bandit edits out.

Comment: I always click "not sure" if code is edited in an answer and I don't understand what's happening...

Comment: I used to do that too, but realised I was just passing the decision on to someone else. The fact that it is a vote means that it is our priviledge/responsibility to indicate what kind of edits we would like to see made on the site -- I believe such edits are wrong, others have the rights to disagree. Overall, the majority will have its way.

Comment: While we're on the topic, I'm keen to know how my vote stands up against others just so I may be swayed by majority decision hence [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110719/hit-rate-for-approval-rejection-of-suggested-edits). Too bad it never took off.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested edits should not change the code shown in an answer; they can change the formatting of the code, if that makes the code more readable, though.
If the code is using the wrong function, a suggested edit should not change the function call with the correct one; if the code is completely wrong, a suggested edit should not change it to a more correct one. In both the cases, who suggested the edit could write her/his own answer.

As the answers is one of yours, you can simply edit it to fix the code.

Comment: *If the code is using the wrong function* -> Really? I *always* accept suggested edits if they fix a *blatant* problem with the code. The times where *my* answers have been updated to fix blatant problems [e.g.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7765196/revisions), I've been grateful.

Comment: Would you accept an edit to an answer written from another user, and that changes `ereg()` with `str_replace()`? _Wrong_ also mean "undesirable or unsuitable."

Comment: Of course not. Would you accept an edit which changed `stringreplace()` to `str_replace()` (typical problem with PHP's lack of naming scheme).

Comment: In that case, I would rather prefer a comment for the author to make her/him notice that. If the user replies with "You are wrong; PHP has `string replace()`." then you know the answer is wrong; if s/he replies with "Oh, you are right. It was a typo." you know s/he just typo-ed the function name.

Comment: Then that's where we disagree I guess :). I'd prefer to accept the edit. The owner gets a notification saying their code has been edited. If they *strongly* disagree with the blatant correction, then they can roll back; but in 99% of the cases, I don't expect that to happen.