# Track flags cast by Community

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderator-tools, community-user, automatic-flags

[The Community user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) casts a number of automatic moderator flags in certain situations: too many rollbacks, too many comments, duplicate answers, consecutive closed questions, questions closed without a comment on a beta site, etc.

I would like to see Community's flagging record. Ideally classified by flag type (to see if certain flags tend to be helpful or not). As a moderator, I do carefully dismiss Community's flags as helpful or not depending on whether I thought that particular situation did warrant involving a moderator.

Unfortunately, I can't find Community's flagging record anywhere. [Community's flag summary](/users/flag-summary/-1) lists only the flags that Community adopted from deleted users.

Please provide a list of Community flags with their resolution, preferably sorted by flag type.

Comment: Related: [Where, precisely does feedback on Community ♦ generated flags go to die?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105813/where-precisely-does-feedback-on-community-generated-flags-go-to-die), about using the feedback from moderators to improve Community's flagging.